# Calculate the area bounded by D in the first Quadrant where $D = \{(x,y): x \le y \le 3x\, , \, 1 \le x \le 2\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the area of $D$ where $D$ placed on the first quadrant and bounded by:
>
> $x \le y \le 3x$ and $1 \le xy \le 2$.
>
> **Hint:** change variables.

My try:

> $x \le y \le 3x \implies 1 \le \frac{y}{x} \le 3$.
>
> Let $u = \frac{y}{x} = y x^{-1}$ and let $v = xy$.
>
> $\implies \{1 \le u \le 3\}, \{1 \le v \le 2\}$.
>
> Calculate the ***Jacobian*** as $J$:
>
> $J = $$
>         \begin{vmatrix}
>         u'_x & u'_y \\
>         v'_x & v'_y \\
>         \end{vmatrix} =
> $$
>         \begin{vmatrix}
>         -yx^{-2} &  x^{-1} \\
>          y & x \\
>         \end{vmatrix} = -yx^{-2}x - yx^{-1} = -yx^{-1}-yx^{-1} = -2yx^{-1}.
> $
>
> $\implies dx\,dy = \frac{1}{J}du\,dv = -\frac{1}{2u}du\,dv$
>
> So the area of $D$ is $-\frac{1}{2} \int_1^2\int_1^3\frac{1}{u}dudv = -\frac{1}{2}\int^2_1 \big|^3_1\ln u \, dv = -\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2(\ln3 -\ln1)\,dv = -\frac{1}{2}(\ln 3-\ln1) \big|^2_1 v =-\ln3-\ln1 + \frac{1}{2}(\ln3-\ln1).$

The book claims the answer is $\ln (\sqrt 3)$.

Where is my problem? THanks in advance.

Comment: Remembar that $\ln(1)=0$ and $\ln\sqrt{x}=\frac12\ln x$.

Comment: @V.Rossetto So my answer is right?..

Comment: I think the transformation is $|J|$, not $J$.